# I'm having issue in search code help me

Tags: c#

its show syntax error while i am search my data

```
   string sql = "Select Name,Father_name,NIC_No,Image from Admform WHERE Member_ID=" + textBoxmember.Text + "";
        if (cn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            cn.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            textBoxname.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            textBoxfname.Text = reader[1].ToString();
            textBoxnic.Text = reader[2].ToString();
            byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[3]);
            if (img == null)
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is does not exist.");
        }
        cn.Close();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. A little brief about the issue you are facing would help us to understand your problem. Are you getting error? or unexpected output?

Comment: syntax error '=' near it....this issue i am having while search my data....execute problem

Comment: @AhadAli: If there's a syntax error in your SQL query, then you should examine your SQL query.  Since it's currently wide open to SQL injection, you could be executing anything at runtime.

Comment: m getting error of incorrect syntax near '='"

Comment: @AhadAli: Yes, you already said that.  Repeating the same information doesn't add new information.

Comment: thanks #David but if i want to make search button which query is best for me ? can u suggest the right way to make search button which retrive all data from data base..in text box..image and datetimepiker

Comment: @AhadAli: Asking to show you how to implement a search feature in your application is far too broad for a Stack Overflow question.  Focus simply on solving the error at hand.  The answers given below should be very helpful, as they correct the SQL injection problem you have which is *very likely* the cause of your error.  Failing that, debug your code to learn more about your error.  Specifically, examine what SQL query you're *actually running* which is causing the syntax error.

Comment: thanks #David and #Mohit sir

Answer (score 1):

First thing first you should use the `Parameterized Query` thus your query becomes

```
string sql = "Select Name,Father_name,NIC_No,Image from Admform WHERE Member_ID=@memid";.

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        var memidParam = new SqlParameter("memid", SqlDbType.Int);
        memidParam.Value = textBoxmember.Text;

        command.Parameters.Add(memidParam);
        var results = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            textBoxname.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            textBoxfname.Text = reader[1].ToString();
            textBoxnic.Text = reader[2].ToString();
            byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[3]);
            if (img == null)
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

or easy would be with `Parameters.AddWithValue`

```
string sql = "Select Name,Father_name,NIC_No,Image from Admform WHERE Member_ID=@memid";.

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memid", textBoxmember.Text);
        command.Parameters.Add ("@p_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value;
        var results = command.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            textBoxname.Text = reader[0].ToString();
            textBoxfname.Text = reader[1].ToString();
            textBoxnic.Text = reader[2].ToString();
            byte[] img = (byte[])(reader[3]);
            if (img == null)
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            else
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This is does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

The use of `using` would help you to destory or dispose automatically once the code block finish. So need to manually close or dispose the objects.

Comment: Reader requires an open and available `SqlConnection` but you forgot to open the connection

Comment: Thanks @un-lucky. Edited. You are always a saver.

Comment: Coolll.... We are all here for helping each other. Happy coding

Comment: where did you open sqldatareader in code @MohitShrivastava

Comment: can you suggest me how to give parameter of datetimepiker....like we are giving of textboxes (textbox,text=reader[0].tostring()); ???

Comment: @AhadAli : you just need to add `command.Parameters.Add ("@p_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value;` BTW also updated the answer with the same

Comment: Happy to help @AhadAli . BTW another way of saying thanks on SO could be you can upvote and if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this

Answer (score 1):

Let me summarize the issues, The column `Member_ID` may not be an integer and you are trying to pass the text without quotes, if you are passing any string values it must be enclosed within a pair of  `'`. But Actually this can be consider as a wrong method since it opens a wide door for the attackers through [Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). So I strongly recomand you to use Paramaterized queries as like this:

```
string querySql = "Select Name,Father_name,NIC_No,Image from Admform WHERE Member_ID=@memid";.

using (SqlConnection conSql = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querySql , conSql ))
    {
        conSql.Open();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memid", textBoxmember.Text);
        SqlDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();
        while(reader.Read())
        {
              // Access your values here
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: yup its not integer :( ...

Comment: can you suggest me how to give parameter of datetimepiker....like we are giving of textboxes (textbox,text=reader[0].tostring()); ???

Comment: your code is working correctly thanks